# IntelliJ Python intellisense doesn't recognize a library added to virtualenvwrapper using add2virtualenv

Tags: python, intellij-idea, intellisense

I moved Python code to another module in the same project and added the module root to a virtualenv using add2virtualenv.

I configured both modules to use the virtualenv python as SDK.

The code runs fine from IntelliJ and from command line, but I get These errors in GUI:

Unresolved reference '...' less... (⌘F1) 
This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.

and I have no autocomplete and IDE functions.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring a source folder in the new module autocomplete and IDE functions were restored.